# How to show if $G$ is a finite group and $H$, $K$ normal subgroups of $G$, then $G = HK$ if and only if $G / (H \cap K) \cong G / H \times G / K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$, $K$ normal subgroups of $G$. Prove that $G=HK$ if and only if $G/(H\cap K)$ is isomorphic to $G/H\times G/K$.

For first part i think I have to take the function $\phi\colon G\rightarrow G/H\times G/K$ defined by $\phi(g)=(gH,gK)$ then the kernel would be $H\cap K$ but I am confusion how to show this function is onto and how to use the fact $G=HK$?

For converse part since H and K be normal then $HK$ be a subgroup of $G$ so clearly $HK\subset G$ but now how to show that $G\subset HK$?

It will be enough if I get a proper hint for both part.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** For the first part, we know that
$$|HK| = \frac{|H|\cdot |K|}{|H \cap K|}$$
So, what can we say about $|H \cap K|$ if $G = HK$ considering $HK \le G$? Also, the function $\phi$ you defined is not surjective unfortunately. Here, using $G = HK$, we can write any element of $g \in G$ as $g = hk$ for some $h \in H$ and $k \in K$ **uniquely**. Now, you may try to define it as $\phi: G \to G/H \times G/K$ such that $\phi(g) = (kH, hK)$. Then, $\phi$ is well-defined since $g = hk$ is a unique way to write $g$. Now, you can either check $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism or check $\phi$ is injective and $|G| = |G/H \times G/K|$ (Since $|G|$ is finite, these two together imply $\phi$ is surjective).

For the second part, we can write
$$\frac{|G|}{|H \cap K|} = \frac{|G|}{|H|}\cdot \frac{|G|}{|K|}$$
Then, what can we say about $|HK|$ considering the above hint for the first part?

Comment: For the second part since HK be a subgroup of G with same order as G then G=HK. Still figuring out the first part

Comment: I am not getting the first hint sorry sir. I want to show that $\phi$ is onto. As far I know H$\cap$K is a subgroup of G and it is the kernel of the function.

Comment: Here what I can think of is kernel is H$\cap$K. But I am not getting that how can it be used to imply that $\phi$ is onto. Honestly  I know you are saying something right but I am not getting that.

Comment: I edited my answer, could you check it again, please?

Comment: Yes this is good. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck :)

Comment: the statement: Let $H, K \lhd G$, then $G = HK$ if and only if $G / (H \cap K) \cong G / H \times G / K$ , does this statement holds even if G is infinite? Can you prove or counter it ? @ArsenBerk

Comment: @MathematicsMan hmm that's an interesting question actually. An immediate counter-example does not come to mind (I tried it for some abelian groups but it seems to hold) but there might be some interesting examples to check as well. If it is true, then going for the Isomorphism Theorems would be a good choice I believe. You may post it as a new question here I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Working with $\phi$ and the first isomorphism theorem is indeed a proper way.

**Hints:**
If $x,y\in KH=HK$ with $x=kh,\,y=h'k'$, then $\phi(kh')=(xH,yK)$.
If $\phi$ is surjective, then $\forall x\in G\,\exists g\in G:\phi(g)=(xH,K)$.